# Proof that $O_3$ and $GL_3$ are homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Proof that $O_3$ and $GL_3$ are **homotopy equivalent**

Trying to use *polar decomposition* to solve this problem and actually I have come to the fact
that exists continuous function $sqrt(AA^T) = C$ where A belongs to $GL_n$ and $C$ is positively defined matrix but Im struggling with proving that it is *homotopic* to the identical

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is on the right road... Yes, for $A\in GL_n$, $AA^t$ has a unique positive definite square root $C$... *and* $A=C\cdot h$ for an orthogonal matrix $h$. And this decomposition is *unique*, is part of the conclusion, with or without the explicit description of the $C$ part.

That is, $GL_n \approx P \times O_n$, where $P$ is positive-definite matrices. Since it's actually a Cartesian product, and the cone $P$ is contractible, any choice of such contraction gives the desired homotopy.